# Node Express render json in ejs not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a js file that controls the inputs of a form, with the express-validator module. In this process, I have this code to send the validation errors to my ejs file

```
var errors = request.validationErrors();
if(errors){
        response.render('./alunos/form_introducao_alunos', {validacao: errors} );
        return;     
    };
```

In my ejs file, I'm trying to display all the errors like this:

```
        <% if(validacao) { %>
        <ul>
            <% for(var i=0; i < validacao.lenth; i++) { %>
                <li> <%= validacao[i].msg%></li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    <% } %>
```

But nothing happens. When trying to debug, I include this code in my ejs file:

```
 var row = <%- JSON.stringify(validacao) %>
 console.log(row)
```

and the json appears in the console.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There's a typo in your template.

Comment: `length` not `lenth`.

Comment: And anyways you can't use *for* to iterate through an object. It's not an array

Comment: It was the length and then it worked.

Comment: Cristian, it's an array of objects.